# Neptune throws Bad handshake error while connecting to a IAM Enabled Neptune Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have an IAM Enabled AWS Neptune instance, I am able to perform crud operations without authentication but when I Enabled authentication it's throws Bad Handshake error logs.

Note: Lambda function has Full Neptune permissions

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
    
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    
    gremlingo "github.com/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin-go/v3/driver"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    v4 "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/signer/v4"
    )

func main() {
    lambda.Start(lambdaHandler)
}

func lambdaHandler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    driverConn, g = connect()
    result, err = g.AddV("User").Property("userId", "Check").Next()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func connect() {
    awsSess, err := session.NewSesionWithOptions(session.Options{
        SharedCondfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }),
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to creating session: %s", err)
    }
    
    db_endpoint := os.Genenv("DB_ENDPOINT")
    connString := "wss://" +db_endpoint+":8182/gremlin"
    
    // Signing Request
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, connString, nil)
    signer := v4.NewSigner(awsSess.Config.Credentials)
    headerToUse, err := signer.Sign(req, nil, "neptune", *awsSess.Config.Region, time.Now())
    
    driverRemoteConnection, err := gremlingo.NewDriverRemoteConnection(connString,
        func(settings *gremlingo.driverRemoteConnectionSettings) {
            settings.TraversalSource = "g"
            settings.AuthInfo.Header = headerToUse
        })
    return driverRemoteConnection, traversalSource(driverRemoteConnection)
}

func traversalSource(driverConn *gremlingo.DriverRemoteConnection) *gremlingo.GraphTraversalSource {
    return gremlingo.Traversal_().WithRemote(driverConn)
}
```

Error Logs:
Failed to instantiate the new connection; setting connection state to closed.
Error creating new connection for connection pool: websocket: bad handshake
'E0104: no successful connections could be made: websocket: bad handshake'

Note: I am able to execute queries if IAM Authentication is disabled. Please help.

Tried signing request but unable to authentication is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things to fix in the code that should get it working with Neptune IAM, provided all necessary permissions are granted.

1. The service name in IAM signer for Neptune should be `neptune-db` instead of `neptune`.
2. The type `*gremlingo.driverRemoteConnectionSettings` should be `*gremlingo.DriverRemoteConnectionSettings`.
3. The header to use for `settings.AuthInfo.Header` is actually not the header returned by the signer, but the header of the original request, so it should be `settings.AuthInfo.Header = req.Header`.

To put it together, the chunk of code under `//Signing Request` would look like this:

```
    // Signing Request
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, connString, nil)
    signer := v4.NewSigner(awsSess.Config.Credentials)
    _, err := signer.Sign(req, nil, "neptune-db", *awsSess.Config.Region, time.Now())
    
    driverRemoteConnection, err := gremlingo.NewDriverRemoteConnection(connString,
        func(settings *gremlingo.DriverRemoteConnectionSettings) {
            settings.TraversalSource = "g"
            settings.AuthInfo.Header = req.Header
        })
```

One thing to note is gremlin-go currently don't have a way to allow automatic refresh of the auth token, which means a new connection will have to be made after expiry.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can now perform automatic refresh thanks to this pr: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/1989.

As such, here's a code sample that takes advantage of the new functionality.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"

    gremlingo "github.com/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin-go/v3/driver"
    v4 "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/signer/v4"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    db_endpoint := "a-gremilincluster-1.cluster-ro-randomstring.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com"
    connString := "wss://" + db_endpoint + ":8181/gremlin"

    // Signing Request
    const emptyStringSHA256 = `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, connString, strings.NewReader(""))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("unable to load AWS SDK config: %w", err))
    }
    cr, err := cfg.Credentials.Retrieve(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("unable to retrieve AWS credentials: %w", err))
    }
    signer := v4.NewSigner()

    gen := func() gremlingo.AuthInfoProvider {
        err := signer.SignHTTP(ctx, cr, req, emptyStringSHA256, "neptune-db", "us-east-1", time.Now())

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        return gremlingo.HeaderAuthInfo(req.Header)
    }

    auth := gremlingo.NewDynamicAuth(gen)

    driverRemoteConnection, err := gremlingo.NewDriverRemoteConnection(connString,
        func(settings *gremlingo.DriverRemoteConnectionSettings) {
            settings.TraversalSource = "g"
            settings.AuthInfo = auth
            //settings.TlsConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true} Use this only if you're on a Mac running Go 1.18+ doing local dev. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51991

        })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    // Cleanup
    defer driverRemoteConnection.Close()

    // Creating graph traversal
    g := gremlingo.Traversal_().WithRemote(driverRemoteConnection)

    // Add a vertex with properties to the graph with the terminal step Iterate()
    promise := g.AddV("gremlin").Property("language", "go").Iterate()

    // The returned promised is a go channel to wait for all submitted steps to finish execution and return error.
    err = <-promise
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    // Get the value of the property
    result, err := g.V().HasLabel("gremlin").Values("language").ToList()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    // Print the result
    for _, r := range result {
        fmt.Println(r.GetString())
    }
}
```