# problem with AWS neptuneDB Golang GremlinGo

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, amazon-neptune

I am working with neptuneDB AWS. I want to test locally on my Ubuntu. I wrote some code for that but it's not working. Although I've secret credentials. I want to write and test the basic crud with Gremlin locally. I want to write and test the basic crud with Gremlin locally. But I can't and doesn't fix this code. this is my code sample

```
   package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/neptune"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/neptune/types"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/credentials"
)

const (
    ACCESS_KEY = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
    SECRET_KEY = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
)

func main() {
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        config.WithRegion("us-west-2"),
        config.WithCredentialsProvider(credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, "")),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to load AWS config", err)
    }

    svc := neptune.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    // Insert data
    err = insertData(svc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to insert data", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Data inserted successfully")

    // Update data
    err = updateData(svc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to update data", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Data updated successfully")

    // Delete data
    err = deleteData(svc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to delete data", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Data deleted successfully")

    // Read data
    _, err = readData(svc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to read data", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Data read successfully")
}

// Insert data
func insertData(svc *neptune.Client) error {
    query := "g.addV('Person').property('name', 'John').property('age', 30).property('em', 'eer')"
    _, err := executeGremlinQuery(svc, query)
    return err
}

// Update data
func updateData(svc *neptune.Client) error {
    query := "g.V().has('name', 'John').property('age', 31)"
    _, err := executeGremlinQuery(svc, query)
    return err
}

// Delete data
func deleteData(svc *neptune.Client) error {
    query := "g.V().has('name', 'John').drop()"
    _, err := executeGremlinQuery(svc, query)
    return err
}

// Read data
func readData(svc *neptune.Client) ([]byte, error) {
    query := "g.V().has('name', 'John')"
    result, err := executeGremlinQuery(svc, query)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("Result:", result)
    return result, nil
}

// Execute a Gremlin query
func executeGremlinQuery(svc *neptune.Client, query string) ([]byte, error) {
    input := &types.ExecuteStatementInput{
        GremlinQueryString: &query,
    }
    output, err := svc.ExecuteStatement(context.TODO(), input)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return output.Items[0].Properties["value"].Value.([]byte), nil
}
```

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: Are you saying the SigV4 with Amazon Neptune is not working or that you cannot even get the Go client to work locally? How are you trying to test locally - Gremlin server or something else? You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75730330/neptune-throws-bad-handshake-error-while-connecting-to-a-iam-enabled-neptune-ins/75738366#75738366) helpful.

Comment: @TrygviLaksafoss I got a lot of issues. When i was tried to ```go mod tidy``` it did give me lot of error

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I would like to run on my local pc using mock server also write some test cases. But some packages did not install correctly. I cant find that issue while i run ```go mod tidy```

Answer (score 3):

If you trying to connect to Neptune using Go, the recommended way is to use the gremlin-go driver instead of the aws-sdk-go (see Neptune docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-go.html)).

Additional gremlin-go information can be found in the TinkerPop [reference docs](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-go). Note that gremlin-go has slightly different step syntax to match the Go language, if you'd like to submit scripts using Groovy syntax instead, see instructions [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-go-scripts).

If you are trying to use SigV4 signing to connect to IAM database using gremlin-go, you can follow [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75730330/neptune-throws-bad-handshake-error-while-connecting-to-a-iam-enabled-neptune-ins/75738366#75738366) that Kelvin linked.

Hope this helps.